# RTL Primeng drop-down component

Tags: css, angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

Is there any way to place the PrimeNG drop-down icon on left side of select?

I tried

```
<div class="ui-rtl" dir="rtl">
    <p-dropdown></p-dropdown>
</div>
```

but didn't work correctly.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: What do you mean exactly ? Because by default, the arrow icon is on the right...

Comment: @Antikhippe Checkout persian or arabic website or other right to left languages, In these examples you see arrow button on left side

Comment: Ok but you asked to place the icon on the right side, can you edit your question please ?

Comment: @antikhippe of course, thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to override PrimeNG CSS ?

Try this :

```
.ui-dropdown .ui-dropdown-label {
  padding-left: 2em;
}

.ui-dropdown .ui-dropdown-trigger {
  left: 0;
}
```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mupvnO4fs20uGAwm110C?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You must override PrimeNG.
don't use direction for .body{}

```css
.ui-dropdown label.ui-dropdown-label
{
text-align:right;
}


body .ui-dropdown-panel .ui-dropdown-items .ui-dropdown-item, body .ui-dropdown-panel .ui-dropdown-items .ui-dropdown-item-group
{
text-align:right;
}
```